# Ehcache stores data in physical storage instead of in-memory storage - grails 2.x

Tags: grails, grails-orm, ehcache

I had gone through this blog to make use of 2nd level caching in grails

[link](http://mrdustmite.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-ehcache-in-grails.html)

& I made the following changes

in resources.groovy

```
      userCache(
    org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean) {
  }
```

Inside service class

```
    def userCache

public def userCachedList(){
    if (userCache.get("userList")) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...

        userCache.put(
                new net.sf.ehcache.Element("userList",
                list)
                )
    }
...
}
```

Caching works fine but the issue this cached list is stored in physical location. When I start the application, I see .ehcache-diskstore.lock is created in tmp directory.

My settings are

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    //cache.use_structured_entities = false
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
    hibernate.format_sql=false
    hibernate.connection.release_mode='after_transaction'
}
```

ehcache.xml is

```
<ehcache name="myapp">

<!-- Necessary for spring-security-acl plugin-->
<!--<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>-->

<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="20000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    overflowToDisk="false">
    <!-- <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/> -->
 </defaultCache>

 <cache 
    name="owsoo.User"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="50"
    eternal="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    overflowToDisk="false">
    <!-- <cacheEventListenerFactory 
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/> -->
 </cache>

<cache name="aclCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="100000"
       eternal="true"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       statistics="true"
        />
```

What do I need to change in the setting to use in-memory cache instead of physical disk storage?

Answer (score 0):

it seems default values provided in ehcache.xml does not work for beans mentioned in resources.groovy so I added properties here to solve this issue

```
userCache(org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean) { bean ->
           maxElementsInMemory="1000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
    }
```